# TextAppearance_Holo_Large - No resource found

Tags: android, android-layout

When compiling my app I get the following error:

```
android-apt-compiler: ... \res\values-v14\styles.xml:12: error: 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance_Holo_Large.
```

The code it is complaining about is:

```
<style name="Title"  parent="@android:style/TextAppearance_Holo_Large">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 </style>
```

I checked my manifest file and I have set the SDK to:

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="14"
   android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Which i believe allows for using the Holo Themes.

I am using Android Studio though I doubt that is the cause of the error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `TextAppearance.Holo.Large` and not `TextAppearance_Holo_Large`. So change your style like this:

```
<style name="Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Silly me, it is. Thanks loads